# Javascript - Onchange Event for checkbox works only in Firefox and Opera?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

Here are two buttons which I want to change the css display property, depending on the state of a checkbox.

```
    <input type="submit" id="unchecked" class="button red" value="Start My PPI Claim" style="display:block" onclick="location.href = 'https://www.gladstonebrookes.co.uk/extended-form';" />
<input type="submit" id="checked" class="button yellow" name="submit" value="Start My PPI Claim" style="display:none" onClick="javascript:return fncValidateForm(this)" />
```

Here is the code for the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this)" />
```

And finally the Javascript function

```
function toggleCheckbox (element) {
    if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("checked").style = "display:block";
        document.getElementById("unchecked").style = "display:none";
            }
    else if(!element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("checked").style = "display:none";
        document.getElementById("unchecked").style = "display:block"; 
  }  
}
```

This works fine in Firefox and Opera but nothing happens Onchange in Chrome, Safari and IE. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
function toggleCheckbox (element) {
    if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("checked").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("unchecked").style.display = "none";
            }
    else if(!element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("checked").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("unchecked").style.display = "block"; 
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works great, I'll set as the answer shortly. Just out of interest is the initial Javascript incorrect and FF and Opera just more forgiving to poor code?

Comment: I wonder your inital code is working after all. The style property is meant to be used this way. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).

Answer (score 0):

Tidy version if you like:

```
function toggleCheckbox (element) {
var b1 = !element.checked ? "none" : "block";
var b2 = !element.checked ? "block" : "none";
document.getElementById("checked").style.display = b1;
document.getElementById("unchecked").style.display = b2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Super quick JQuery fix, :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkbox").click(function (){
        $('#unchecked, #checked').toggle();
    });    
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/LnEyD/)